# What happens in a program that is linked to a dll through a static .lib before any of the program code is executed?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-c++-6

This is a complex situation.  The exe loading delays approximately 10 minutes before any of the program or dll code is executed.  Both the program and dll were written in-house.  Using an earlier version of the dll seems to alleviate the problem.  What I am trying to determine is what happens in the compiler generated code to attach the dll to a program and how that could result in a delay of several minutes on loading the program.  Both the program and the dll were produced using VC++ 6.0.  This started happening after a dll revision about 1 year ago, but the revision had nothing to do with any of the dll initialization/start up code.  This does not happen on all computers, nor does it affect all programs that make use of the dll on any given computer.  There does not seem to be any pattern to the failure.

Comment: The application and/or DLL can do a lot of things upon startup, e.g. in `DllInitialize()` or in constructors of any global/static objects - check those. You can put some logging to the beginning of `main()` (or `MessageBox()` at beginning of `WinMain`) to see when the main actually started.

Comment: So what happens during those 10 minutes (when the dll code gets called)? Is the app frozen? Or it's doing something else? How did you test that (added some code in `DllMain`)? Is the dll linked into the app (the app won't start if the dll is not present), or it's loaded via `LoadLibrary`, or is it [delay loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790(v=vs.71).aspx)?

Comment: The title is rather confusing. A _static_ .lib means you **don't** link to a DLL. When using DLL's, you'd use an _import_ .lib.

Comment: @ axalis - They are MFC projects; I don't have access to those methods/functions otherwise I would do exactly that.

Comment: @ CristiFati - It's linked through an import library so it has to be there.  This only happens on a select few machines; on most it functions as expected.  It appears to be waiting; there is no excessive use of the processor during the delay.  I'm not really sure what it's doing during the delay, but I suspect if I could figure that out I'd solve the problem.

Comment: @ n.m - If all you can do is make sideways comments, why are you here?  The project was created about 20 years ago using VC6++, and has been maintained using that tool.  The task of converting 130+ programs in the application suite is quite time consuming and expensive.  Are you going to pay for it?

Comment: @ MSalters - Thanks for the clarification and answer.

Answer (score 0):

"What happens in the compiler generated code to attach the dll to a program?"

Almost nothing. The compiler-generated code exists in the DLL, not the EXE. It has three essential tasks: make sure the C++ runtime is loaded, call constructors for global objects, and calling `DllMain`. Note that the last two parts of generated code merely call *your* code; the generated code itself executes in nanoseconds.